# Google Chrome Undo Closed Tab Command

Tags: google-chrome

I  would like to set up a button or the combination of button to undo recently closed tab in Google Chrome.

I know on OSX you can do this, but I want it on PC.

Is there any way to make this option on PC in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you want but the key combination in Chrome to undo recently closed tab is:

- **PC:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- **Mac:** <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

If you right-click on the tab bar's background, you will see a context menu that gives this key combination as a hint:

[image: Context Menu from Chrome]

Comment: This not only works in Chrome, but also Firefox, Opera (pre-Webkit, too) and IE (8+). In reality, it is a de facto "standard" key combination on the PC.

Comment: That just opens a new tab, the poster wants to then select the latest 'recently closed' tab

Comment: Control+shift+tab opens the previously closed tab on my chrome browser. Control+tab opens a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a keyboard macro and then find a way to bind it to a button:

Ctrl+Shift+T
Tab six times
Down arrow
Enter

At least, that works on my screen, maybe if you have different options on it will take more or less tabs...not very elegant.